# power calculation for stepper motor

Tags: power, stepper-motor

Power calculation for stepper motor with 1.2 Ampers and 4 volts.
Is P = V * I enough for this? If not, should I do a separate operation with torque?

Comment: Power consumed by (or generated by) a component is the current flow through it times the voltage across its terminals. However, the stepper motor probably won't be sinking a constant current during the normal operation. A better approach would have been using it for a while, gathering data, and then taking the mean of the data.

Comment: Can we calculate if we know the average working time?